# PopupMenu implementation that hacks inflating a @MenuRes

Tags: java, android

**Summary**

`Usage` will ask for a `Context` and a `@MenuRes` and then use the `PopupHack.class` to inflate the menu resource and retrieve the `Menu` and `MenuItems`.

**Reasoning**

To allow the creation of a `List<Object>` by supplying a menu resource xml. For use within a larger project/library.

**PopupHack.class**

```
static class PopupHack extends PopupMenu {
    PopupHack(Context context, int menuRes) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions or (new View(context)?)
        super(context, null);
        inflate(menuRes);
    }

    int size(){
        return getMenu().size();
    }

    CharSequence title(int index) {
        return getMenu().getItem(index).getTitle();
    }

    Drawable icon(int index) {
        return getMenu().getItem(index).getIcon();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
 public static void usage(@NonNull Context context, @MenuRes int menuRes){
    final PopupHack hack = new PopupHack(context, menuRes);
    for (int i = 0; i < hack.size(); i++) {
        final CharSequence title = hack.title(i);
        final Drawable icon = hack.icon(i);
        Log.i("Usage", String.format("Title: %s Icon: %s", title, icon));
    }
}
```

The code is completely operational.